# How do I make a NetBeans 7.1 tutorial work with NetBeans 7.2 with the new wizard for New File Type

Tags: java, module, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

The title is a bit long, but the description of the problem is quite easy to understand.

I have NetBeans 7.2 and I am following a tutorial that is intended for NetBeans 7.1 . The tutorial shows how to add Language Support to highlight custom Syntax.

http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-javacc-lexer.html

The problem is that NetBeans 7.1's "New File Type" Wizard is creating two files (layer.xml & SJResolver.xml) which are not created by NetBeans 7.2's version of this Wizard.

I found a link explaining that layer.xml can be created by another Wizard (see below link)

http://platform.netbeans.org/whatsnew/71.html

but haven't found any explanation on the missing Resolver.xml and how to create it.

So before I install NetBeans 7.1 and retry I thought of checking here if there is a simpler way to make the leap from 7.1 to 7.2 and make this tutorial work for me.

Thanks,

--- RaamEE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked the qustion 2 days ago and today I install NetBeans 7.1 and opened the tutorial to follow it again.

Between today and 2 days ago, Netbeans.org updated the tutorial and it is now for NetBeans 7.2

The tutorial is under the same link as above.
Old 7.1 tutorial was moved.

RaamEE